# My Simple XML returns Empty Data

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying a simple XML and XSL linked program but XML uses the XSL in a perfect way. The data from XML is not included in the table.

The file successfully shows the table heading but the contents are not shown. Is this the correct way to fetch all values from the XML on XSLT?

database.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"?>
<Apple>
<prdt>
<name>iPhone</name>
<typ>Mobile Phone</typ>
<price>60,000</price>
</prdt>
<prdt>
<name>iPod</name>
<typ>Music Player</typ>
<price>60,000</price>
</prdt>
<prdt>
<name>iPad</name>
<typ>Tablet</typ>
<price>60,000</price>
</prdt>
<prdt>
<name>iTunes</name>
<typ>Software</typ>
<price>60,000</price>
</prdt>
</Apple>
```

style.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/WSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>database.xml</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th><h1>Device Name</h1></th>
                <th><h1>Device Type</h1></th>
                <th><h1>Price</h1></th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="Apple/prdt">
            <tr>
                <td><h1><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h1></td>
                <td><h1><xsl:value-of select="typ"/></h1></td>
                <td><h1><xsl:value-of select="price"/></h1></td>
            </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </center>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XSL is OK, it's just that you have the wrong namespace. Replace

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/WSL/Transform" version="1.0">
```

with

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
```